# How to make a unordered list using fetch_assoc from database and arrays

Tags: php, database, list, mysqli, unordered

Trying to create a list by selecting booking references from the database, sorting them into an array and then having each array value passed into each item on the list. e.g. first booking reference on the first item, second reference on the second item etc... 
Here is the code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Manage booking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Oadby Granville Tennis Club Manage Booking</h3>
    <br><br><br>
    <?php 
    include "dbconnect.php";
    session_start();

    $login_ID = $_SESSION['id'];
    $query = "SELECT Booking_ID
              FROM  `booking`
              WHERE Login_ID = '$login_ID';";


    $bookingArray = array();

    $result = $mysqli -> query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       printf ("%s<br>", $reference = $row["Booking_ID"]);
       array_push($bookingArray, $reference . "<br>");
     }
     print_r ($bookingArray);
     ?>

    <table border="1" style="width:50%">
      <caption>Please select a booking to edit:</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <ul style="list-style-type:circle">
            <?php
            $arrayNo = 1;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              printf ("<li><a href='UpdateBooking.php'>Booking ID:%s</a>" . $bookingArray[$arrayNo] . "</li><br>");
              $arrayNo = $arrayNo + 1;
            }
            ?>
            <li><a href="UpdateBooking.php">Booking ID</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ignore the code before the table, that is just for  my reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {..}` transfers everything  into `$bookingArray` until the result set is exhausted. With your second `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {..}` you don't get anything more. Additionally, your use of printf is weired.
Try this instead your second loop:

```
foreach($bookingArray as $Booking)
{
   echo "<li><a href='UpdateBooking.php'>Booking ID:$Booking</a></li><br>";
}
```

However, `UpdateBooking.php` wont know which booking should be changed. So you should consider to append the BookingId to the URL.

Edit 2016-03-02:
To append the BookingId to the URL you should try:

```
foreach($bookingArray as $Booking)
{
   echo "<li><a href='UpdateBooking.php?BookingId=" . urlencode($Booking) . "'>Booking ID:$Booking</a></li><br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. How do I append the $booking of the item on the list thats clicked to the URL for the next page to use it?